# Securely store authentication credentials in a web extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

What is the best practice for securely storing authentication credentials in a web extension? e.g. The user enters their username and password, and the extension saves these credentials in order to authenticate to an API in the future.

Currently, I have been using the sync storage, but was wondering if this has the same level of protection as saved passwords in the browser (for example, getting encrypted with a master password)?

Or, is there a method to store/retrieve the login details in the browser's password storage (but, obviously not being able to retrieve any other passwords)?

Do any of the answers above change if storing an API token, rather than full login credentials?

Comment: Absolutely everything your extension stores or processes in a client browser can be inspected by the user in devtools debugger.

Comment: I'm not trying to obfuscate things from the user, I'm trying to ensure their data is protected properly. As a user, I expect that if I add a master password to encrypt my login details, no passwords would be stored unencrypted. I also expect any stored passwords to not be leaked to other extensions or scripts running in web pages, etc.

Comment: Regardless of the intent anything you even temporarily decrypt locally inside the extension can be viewed by the user, even if you store the encrypted value but decrypt it for actual use. As for other extensions or web pages they don't have access to your extension's chrome.storage or any DOM storage of your chrome-extension://id/ pages like the popup or the background script. However another extension (see Storage Area Explorer) can access all of it via its own devtools panel when the user explicitly opens it on your extension's page.

Comment: I would suggest having a look at the [Credential Management API](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/credential-management/). However, it currently only seems to be available in Chrome.

Comment: @wOxxOm Again, I'm not trying to hide anything from the user, so whether the user can view it is completely irrelevant to the discussion (I even mentioned that the user is entering these details into the extension..). If using the storage as I currently do is the best practice, then that's fine. But, I'm still suspecting that the browser doesn't encrypt it with the master password. Also, you say that another extension can't access the storage, but then say that Storage Area Explorer can? I don't see any permissions that would suggest that it can access that.

Comment: @PetrSrníček That looks promising (if the spec becomes a widely implemented standard in the future), although it's not clear to me whether it can be used in a web extension.

Comment: 1) Credentials API [doesn't work in extensions yet](https://crbug.com/707900). 2) The important point I was trying to convey is that there's no "secure" method in the absolute sense of the word (which is the mostly used sense AFAIK), 3) Not sure I can phrase it better than above but here it is - another extension can only access your extension's data when it declares a devtools panel and the user opens devtools on your extension's page and switches to that panel, to see it in action you can install Storage Area Explorer yourself.

Comment: I'm simply asking for the most secure method to store credentials, where the goal is that it should have the same level of security as the user saving login details when logging into a website. If another extension can access a password through devtools, or if the password is not stored encrypted with the master password, then the extension's storage does not provide the same level of security.